# Win XP летает из-за касперского.

Tags: windows, kaspersky

На работе на одном из компов стоит касперский 6.0.2.690 workstation, и как-то мне сказали - посмотри комп, не грузится. Посмотрел, нашел проблему - касперский. Удалил его утилитой с их сайта, снова установил касперского, всё нормально. Через какое-то время снова обращаются - опять тот же косяк. Спрашиваю - после чего такое? Отвечают - наушники в разьем вставили и всё. Первый раз было так же. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема? В журнале код ошибки 7001 кажется был первый раз, второй раз ещё не успел комп посмотреть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наушники точно ни при чем. Скорее всего, проблема при запуске какой-то службы, посмотрите внимательно журналы и логи, там может быть более точное описание. Я думаю, что юзер запустил какое-то приложение (раз наушники -- значит плеер=))), коему было необходимо или в Инет влезть, или драйвер загрузить, или службу запустить, или ино что содеять, а каспер запретил это действие. А вообще, попробуйте сменить антивирь...

Comment: Это на работе, там не сменишь, к сожалению) По службам смотрел, у меня где-то было записано, там что-то было связано по-моему со Службой SSTP. Только каким боком и как решить конфликт, я так и не понял.

Comment: Если Вы не используете VPN, то эту службу можно попробовать отключить. А так же рискнуть безопасностью и отключить пару настроек в каспере. Вернее, просто понизить уровень защиты, чтобы он за системными настройками не следил... И интересно, что написано по поводу служб?

Comment: Завтра гляну точно, что писал журнал. Но вроде последние разы там записи были совсем не касающиеся каспера.  Кстати когда пришел и запустил комп, он включился нормально и никаких сбоев не писалось и каспер нормально работал. Странности какие-то...